# Dirty Form with TabControl

Tags: vb.net

Hi I have a form with a TabControl, 3 tabpages and controls(textboxes and comboboxes) in each tabPage.
I have one event for all the changings of the controls in tabPages (controlValueChanged) and one event for the tabControl.SelectedIndexChanged.
So I want to my  button (btnOK) enabled if the form is Dirty.

```
Private Sub controlValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
     If bLoading=False 'bLoading is a boolean that is true after I create and populate the controls
        Dirty = True 'Dirty is a boolean property
     End If
End Sub
```

So when I change something in one of my controls the event is fired and btnOK is Enabled.
The problem is that the first time that I change (visiting) to a tabPage the controls is that TabPage fire the  controlValueChanged event causing my button to Enabled even if I haven't changed anything in my controls.
If I am visiting a TabPage for second time the event is not fired.
I know that this is normal but how I can overcome this problem and have my Dirty =true only if the control is fired because of something is changing and not when the tabPage is changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a new boolean variable - **DoNotMakeDirty**, say, then you could, in the `TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged` sub, set `DoNotMakeDirty = True` and then put an if statement in your `controlValueChanged` sub.

Comment: The problem is that when I am changing TabPage, first is firing the controlValueChanged event for the controls in that TabPage and then the TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: ... I'm sorry, I missed your comment, but I tried to re-create your problem and it works fine for me - I made a form with a tab control with 2 tabs and 2 comboboxes and the event only fired once I changed the index of the comboboxes, as expected...

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I create everything dynamically. I am using the event TabPage_Enter, that is fired prior to controlValueChanged.

Comment: So, to understand, you are re-creating / re-filling the controls each time the tab is entered.... Yes that would fire off the control's events... It ouwld also slow down your form execution A LOT... If that is the case (which I would look into perhaps changing a bit), then just set the bLoading = False before creating the controls... no?

Comment: No. Sorry If I am not explain myslef correctly.I am creating the controls dynamically. The definitions for the controls (how many, what type, properties) are coming from an xml. So everything is dynamically created. For controls like textbox,combobox I add the event controlValueChanged. So I don't build the controls in design mode, but in runtime. Thus I don't recreate anything. I create each control, once, BUT the event COntrolValueChanged is fired first time when I ma visiting for first time a tabPage

Comment: I'm sorry, man, I'm trying to re-create your issue, but I'm not getting the controls events firing like you are.... If you could update your code a bit more to show how this is happening for you, that would help, but my events are firing correctly....

Comment: It doesn't matter, since I solved it. 
You are right though.My project is too big to add here more code, but I simulate it and you are right. Maybe the problem is because I use databinding when I put values in my controls. Thanks for your time